# Add a text prefix to variation price in WooCommerce variable product pages

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

Using the WordPress Astra theme, I want to add a text after a `<div>` that has `woocommerce-variation-price` as class attribute,  where the price of WooCommerce product variations is displayed

I want to dynamically add the prefix *"Total Price: "* to variation price in WooCommerce variable product pages, so it will display as *"Total Price: $XX.XX"* on the front end. I want this prefixed text to be displayed after:

```
<div class="woocommerce-variation-price">
```

Since I don't have direct access to the theme's files, I am using the WordPress Code Snippets plugin to add custom PHP code to my WordPress site.

I have tried implementing JavaScript solutions, but they didn't work in my scenario. Now I am looking for a PHP based approach.

Here are some images:

I want to change this:

[image]

To this

[image]

I have attempted adding that prefix text to the `woocommerce-variation-price` CSS class. I tried also modifying the *functions.php* file in my WordPress theme and adding some JavaScript code directly. However, these attempts didn't yield the desired results.

Despite my efforts, the prefix wasn't added as expected. I'm now seeking guidance on how to accomplish this task using PHP within the WordPress environment, specifically using the Code Snippets plugin.

Any help or example code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use css `::before`. Including the following should do the trick, or at least get you on your way:

```
<style>
.woocommerce-variation-price::before{
    content: 'Total price';
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following pure PHP code snippet, that will **add your custom text prefix** to the product variation price in WooCommerce single variable product pages:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'woocommerce_prefixed_get_price_html', 10, 3 );
function woocommerce_prefixed_get_price_html( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
    $show_variation_price = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_variation_price', $variation->get_price() === '' || $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min' ) !== $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'max' ) || $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min' ) !== $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max' ), $product, $variation );

    if ( $show_variation_price ) {
        $variation_price_prefix       = '<span class="prefix">' . __('Total Price:', 'woocommerce') . '</span> ';
        $variation_data['price_html'] = '<span class="price">' . $variation_price_prefix . $variation->get_price_html() . '</span>';
    }
    return $variation_data;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

You will get the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="woocommerce-variation-price">
    <span class="price">
        <span class="prefix">Total Price:</span> 
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
            <bdi>
                <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span> 1,500.00
            </bdi>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Instead of WooCommerce default one:

```
<div class="woocommerce-variation-price">
    <span class="price">
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
            <bdi>
                <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span> 1,500.00
            </bdi>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: @GESAN As this answer works and answer your question could you please accept this answer *(To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in)*, thank you.